# Including JQuery library in VF page causing Apex tab not switching

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I have  a visual force page where I have these two libraries at the top.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
```

I have another page with two tabs.
I included both these pages in another page.Tabs on second page not switching. So I trouble shooted and commented two scripts for libraries.Tabs started working. If I include JQuery.noconflict as shown below, tabs did not switch.  How can I make the tabs work without commenting the scripts. Any suggestions???

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">
</script>
<script>
if(jQuery) {

    jQuery.noConflict();
         }
</script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
if(jQuery) {

    jQuery.noConflict();
         }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your code, which can better explain the issue

Comment: Well it not make any sense, why you are using two jQuery versions?

Comment: Try with following jQuery noconflict syntax, i.e , `j$= jQuery.noConflict( true )`

Comment: Trying all combinations. I jut used JQuery.noConflict() It did not work. I cant post the rest of the code since it is client specific.

Comment: Still, I'm confused with one thing, I believe your are using `<apex:include>` for including two pages into one, In that case, it is not required to be use two different jQuery there, is there any specific need ?

Comment: Thank you user2809299. You saved me today. It worked.Can you post your comment under answer so that I can accept your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the jQuery documentation, it is not recommended to use two JQuery version on the page, But if you are using then you should initialize the `jQuery.noconfict()` syntax with a added parameter like `jQuery.noconfict(true)`, Here is the reference:

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version
>   will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/